# How can I profile serialization overhead in my application

Tags: .net, serialization, profiling

My application has a WCF service tier between the front-end and the database.  Since we currently host in IIS6 we are using SOAP over HTTP.  How can I find out how much real world time I am spending doing serialization activities in my application?

Comment: Brian - what OS are you needing to profile on?   The client, or the server... which product?  Thanks :)  Foredecker...

Comment: Server.  2K3 or 2K8.  The code is a running in two iis6 app pools that are talking...

Comment: Re your comment (to me) - what podcast? Do you mean Jon Skeet, by any chance? Drop me a line if you have any issues getting the WCF bits working: they do work, honest!

Comment: (re comment): no "h"; Jon's ;-p

Answer (score 4):

Not about measuring - but about improving: I've been working on [protobuf-net](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/), an implementation of Google's "protocol buffers" (a compact, low-CPU binary serialization format) for use with .NET - including a WCF hook (to replace the DataContractSerializer). It has some [pretty good metrics](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/wiki/Performance) re serialization.

When used with the basic http binding, it also works with MTOM, so you don't even get the base-64 overhead of binary. There is a WCF sample [here](http://code.google.com/p/protobuf-net/source/browse/#svn/trunk/WcfPerfTest).

It might be of interest...

Comment: Listen to a podcast you gave on this. Sounds interesting.  The link to the WCF sample comes up empty, but I'll poke around some more and see how feasible this may be to remove serialization overhead as a major concern.

Comment: Thanks for the correction, it ws John's podcast on dotnetrocks.

Answer (score 1):

Create a message inspector and add it to your endpoint behavior,

In the message inspector, you implement the interface which has the following method

```
AfterReceiveRequest
{
  DateTime start = datetime.now;
  return start;
}
BeforeSendReply
{
 // start will be passed in as state in the parameter.  
 TimeSpan period = datetime.now - start 
}
```

Comment: This should isolate server time from transport time.  Any idea if there is a way to hook in before 1st packet sent to isolate the protocol serialization from the actual network overhead?

Answer (score 0):

One of the dead simple things old mainframes always used to to was to include a "sever time" field in the response. Therefore you'd know that anything that happened between your observed time and server time is network/serialization overhead. I know it kind of 1960-ish, but it still works well.

If you want avoid changing the method signature you can set it in a http response header or something ;)

Answer (score 0):

The [xperf tools](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx) are a good choice if you can run on Windows Server 2008 and Vista on the client.  These are ETW based and use the Windows sample profile interrupt to profile anything running on the system. Here is [series of posts](http://blogs.msdn.com/pigscanfly/pages/xperf-articles.aspx) on the xperf tools from myself. [This post](http://blogs.msdn.com/pigscanfly/archive/2008/03/02/using-the-windows-sample-profiler-with-xperf.aspx) is specifically about profiling.

note that you can download the latest version of the tools directly for [this page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/performance/default.aspx).

You may want to experiment with some of the other kernel events, such as disk IO and hard faults.

Comment: ETW would probably work.  Any idea what tracing profiles need to be included to trace the WCF execution?  Any idea where to even look for a description of the WCF events?